# Removing NA values in lmBF and undefined columns

Tags: r, dataframe, bayesian

This is my code:

```
HADSD <- data$HADSD

HADSA <- data$HADSA

AccuracyAverage <- data$AccuracyAverage
AccuracyAverage1 <- (na.exclude(AccuracyAverage))

model2bf <- lmBF(AccuracyAverage1 ~ HADSA*HADSD, data=data)
summary(model2bf)
```

I think using the na.exclude function I've solved the issue of not counting the NA values whilst retaining the length of the variable for comparison. However if there is a different way of doing it please let me know!

The code is now giving me this message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , dv) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
data coerced from tibble to data frame
```

My other lmBF calculations usingn HADSD and HADSA have worked out fine, so I'm really not sure what to do next.

I would be extremely grateful for any help. I'm not the most proficient at R so please nothing to complicated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's quite how `na.exclude()` works, because if you do it on a sample example, you can see it actually changes the length of the vector you're creating:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:10),
  y = c(c(1:8), NA, NA)
)

length(df$y)
# > [1] 10
new_y <- na.exclude(df$y)
length(new_y)
# > [1] 8
```

But it looks like you're using the `data` dataframe in your call to `lmBF()`. Since `na.exclude()` is an `na.action` (see more [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/)), you should be able to do this:

```
model2bf <- lmBF(AccuracyAverage ~ HADSA*HADSD, data=data,
                 na.action = na.exclude)
summary(model2bf)
```

With the original `AccuracyAverage` variable

Comment: if works, don't forget to accept the answer :) if not, let me know so we can try another approach!